# Solr 3.1 to 3.6 upgrade syntax changes

Tags: solr, edismax

Tried to upgrade and application from Solr 3.1 to 3.6.1 and stumbled upon the following issue:
The query like the one shown below worked in 3.1 but does not return any results in 3.6.1:

> q=id:911 AND (format:text OR format:null)

**defType** is set to **edismax** and **q.op** set to **AND**.

Could someone please point me to the point in release notes or SOLR documentation that explains when and why the change was introduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason. Just did not believe it could be a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3377). That simple.